# How to display different image based on page direction through CSS?

Tags: html, css

We have a multilingual site, English and Arabic. The page displays 9 images of categories on the homepage and each image has some text on it with the image of the product. Below is the code for the categories which are shown on the homepage:

```
 <div class="container ">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row ms-mt-s home-collection">
            <div ms-widget="ms.entity"   ms-data-entity="ms.categories" ms-data-pagesize="9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="coleections col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 ms-p-xs"
                             data-ng-repeat="record in records">
                            <div class="collection-info ">
                                <div class="collection-image">
                                    <a class="home_cat_image" href="/browse/{{record.alias}}">
                                        <img  ms-widget='ms.responsiveImage'   ms-data-valign='middle'
                                                ms-data-halign='center'
                                                ms-data-placeholder-html='<div class="img-place-holder"><table><tr><td>{{record.name}} <br> &nbsp;380x190<br>Ratio : 2:1</td></tr></table></div>'
                                                ms-data-aspect-ratio='2:1' ng-src="{{record.image|image:'480x480'}}"
                                                alt="..."/>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ms-p-s text-center collection-title hide">
                                     <h4 class=" ms-fs-18 font-bold" style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
                                         <span class=""><a href="/browse/{{record.alias}}">{{record.name}}</a></span>
                                     </h4>
                                 </div>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there any way I can show Arabic images based on the direction of the page. I can upload Arabic images and have the specific URL. I am just confused on how to implement it in the following code.

Kindly help with the code to show Arabic images based on page direction RTL.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Will this do?

```
div {
   direction: rtl;
}
```

or

```
img {
   transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```